# Probability of a poker hand of winning

Tags: probability, probability-theory, recreational-mathematics, game-theory, poker

Just by curiosity I was looking for the probabilities of poker hands as a simple array of 5 cards, and what I found in many websites are the frequencies asociated to each combination of shown in a random pick, as is shown in the first table of the Wiki page for [Poker Probabillities](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poker_probability).

But if I am not mistaken in my intuition, these are the probabillities of "appearance" and not the probabillities of winning, since somehow it must be introduced in each term of the table the probabillity that in **the ramainning cards** there aren't any other hand ranking higher, which I think that also will be depending on the number "$n-1$" of others players that have also random sets of 5 cards.

- Is this intuition right?
- Do you know how these winning probabillities of each hand are named?
- There is somewhere the table of hands' winning probabillities vs the number of players considered?
- Does happen in any point of players considered that there is a flip in possition of the ranking of hands comparing the frequency ranking vs the winning probability ranking?

Thanks beforehand!

Comment: Extremely complicated problem.  For example, suppose that you have a $(5)$ handed game, and you have a pair of $(10)$'s.  What is the probability that none of the other players can beat your hand?  Further, within this, what is the probability that one of the other players exactly ties you?  Here, you have to distinguish, for example between (10-spades), (10-hearts), + 3 other hearts, and (instead) + 3 other diamonds.  The probability of someone making (for example) a flush are affected by whether you have $(4)$ hearts.  In my opinion, your entire problem is best left to computers.

Comment: If I was attempting to use a computer to answer the question, I would feel compelled to have the computer spin through each of the $$\binom{52}{5} \times \binom{47}{5} \times \cdots \times \binom{32}{5} ~\text{possibilities}.$$  For what it's worth, my pc is okay handling $(10)^7$ different situations, but is very slow to handle $(10)^8$ different situations.

Comment: @user2661923 I was thinking, as example of 3 players, if the prob. of having a straight flush is $p_1=\frac{36}{ {52}\choose{5}}$, which is only weaker than a royal flush, if the prob. of the other player having it is $p_2=\frac{4}{{47}\choose{5}}$ and both having royal flush is $p_3=\frac{4}{{47}\choose{5}}\frac{3}{{42}\choose{5}}$, then the prob of other player **not having** royal flush is $p_4=1-(2\ p_2-p_3)$ so then the prob. of straight flush winning is $p(\text{SF win})=p_1 p_4$... Does this make sense?

Comment: It is much more complicated than that.  You have correctly computed $p_3$, which represents the probability of Player-2 and Player-3 both having a royal flush.  However, computing the probability that neither Player-2 nor Player-3 has a royal flush is complicated.  For example, if Player-2 has $(4)$ 10's and a 9, then it is impossible for Player-3 to have a royal flush.  Also, a further complication: if Player-1 has a straight flush, of unspecified rank, Player-2 (for example) does not need a royal flush to beat Player-1.  I repeat, I suggest using a computer.

Comment: The probability of winning strongly depends on the poker variant you are playing. Here it looks like that you are referring to a single draw poker, which is basically never played. On variants like hold'em, in which there are common cards, with, say, quads you can be both 100% sure to win or just playing to split the pot, depending on your hole cards and the cards on the board.

Comment: @user2661923 I guess there is too much I don't understand. As example, if having a royal flush has a prob. of $p_{a} = \frac{4}{{52}\choose{5}}$, and I am so lucky I have it on my hand, the prob. of anybody else in the table of having also a royal flush is $p_{b} = \frac{3}{{47}\choose{5}}$, but counter-intuitively $p_b > p_a$. Maybe what I need is a set of tables of listing the prob. of appearing after I have a specific hand (like a table for royal flush, other for straight flush, and so on)?

Answer (score 1):

(Not a complete answer, but too long for a comment)

There are some oddities.  For instance, consider the two hands:

$$A\heartsuit,A\diamondsuit, A\clubsuit, K\heartsuit, K\diamondsuit\quad \quad \&\quad \quad  K\heartsuit, K\diamondsuit, K\clubsuit, A\spadesuit, A\heartsuit $$

The left one is nominally stronger.  That is, if both hands were to occur in the same game (not possible, of course) then the left one would win.  But because of the way the suits are selected, there are fewer hands that beat the one on the right, so it is the better hand to be dealt.  Specifically, the left hand can be beaten by an ace high spade straight flush which the suit selection blocks in the second case.

As the example suggests, you have to go to extremes to get this sort of effect, but it is possible.

Comment: Pandora's box.  For example, given A-spades, A-hearts, A-diamonds,King,Queen, is your hand stronger with King,Queen of hearts, or King,Queen of clubs, or King of clubs, Queen of hearts?

Comment: @user2661923  In each case, you just have to count the hands which can beat the given hand.  That's, surely, the best definition of strength.  Almost always that coincides with the ordering provided by the Rules of Play, but not always.

Comment: The point of my comment was that in the specific scenario, my intuition is lacking.  I can't (immediately) tell, which of the $(3)$ options best deters a flush.

Comment: As another anomaly, if you have two pairs, 9's and 6's, it is clearly better if your kicker is a King, rather than an Ace.  However, it is unclear (to me) whether it is better to have a King kicker, a 10 kicker, or an 8 kicker.

Comment: @user2661923  In my example, the count is relatively easy.  Any (possible) four of a kind beats either full house.  No other (possible) full house does.  All straight flushes starting with $Q$ or lower beat both.   No  Royal Flushes can beat the right hand, but the spade flush beats the left.  Two king high straight flushes beat the left, but only one beats the right.  That's it.

Comment: Yes I certainly agree with your analysis.  This is why my first comment mentioned *Pandora's box*.

Comment: Five-high straight flushes are also relevant, though the count still favors the left at 32:31

Comment: @DanielMathias  Yes!  Thanks for catching that.